# Where can I find Goblin Scouts?

Tags: terraria

In Terraria 1.0.6, the Goblin Scout was added — however, he's not part of the Goblin Invasion.

Where might I find this elusive beast?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a chance for the Goblin Scout to appear randomly near the edges of the world. The [official wiki](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Goblin_Scout) says they will not spawn in the middle third, however the [Wikia wiki](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Goblin_Scout) only says they are found most often near the edge with no mention of them being completely unable to spawn in the middle third.

Both these cases are probably anecdotal evidence, so you may have to wait a little longer for more playtesting to determine where it spawns the most. For what it's worth, I was lingering just inside the Dungeon entrance when I had one spawn nearby.

Comment: I don't think the Dungeon itself really counts as a biome, where the Jungle does. If I had to guess, it's probably all above-ground areas equally, or just in grassy areas. I agree on the need to wait, though.

Comment: in terraria, biomes are determined by the blocks on screen. so you can create your own meteorite biome or corruption by placing 50 of the corresponding block (meteorite or ebonstone). dungeon and jungle are both biomes.

Comment: Accepting because the wiki's actually right. FWIW, they don't spawn on sand or corruption.

Answer (score 0):

If u want goblin scouts you can summon them in the same way you would summon slime kings: just cover one of the "end of the world oceans" with dirt or stone and they might spawn. However, that is also where a ton of slimes and the slime king can spawn as well. Test your luck :)

Answer (score -1):

After 15-20 hours of testing, here is a list on the conditions I found for goblin scouts to spawn.

- Goblin scouts will start to spawn when you have managed to reach maximum Health or HP (400 Health).
- They all spawned on the *dungeon* third of the map.
- They all spawned in the time 4.00pm-7.00pm (in-game). You can find out the time by right clicking a grandfather clock or by wearing a watch in your inventory....
- Jungle does not seems to affect the chance of goblin scouts spawning
- Goblin scouts have never spawned on sand for me but they have spawned on dungeon bricks.
- I have found that one goblin scout can spawn once a day (in-game) in the designated time. (4.00pm-7.00pm)
- After 3 goblin scouts have spawned an automatic goblin army will attack the very next day. (might be different for every world)
- If you kill goblin scouts in a row day after day, no goblin army will spawn...

Comment: I've actually done some code digging since asking this question and, well... most of this isn't true. For example, I have no idea where you're getting the "400 health" or "automatic goblin army" parts from.